# is "synchronizeFile" needed to guarantee file integrity on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, file-io

I have a problem in an iPhone application where some files that appear to be fine when the app runs appear with 0 size on some occasions when the application restarts.  I have checked my code all over.   The way these files are written is basically :

```
   NSFileHandle *fHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: myFileName];
   do 
   {
        // code to set value of myNSData
        [fHandle writeData: myNSData];
        // some more logic here
   } 
   while (!done)

   [fHandle closeFile];
```

I have seen the problem happen both in the simulator and on the real device.  It only happens sporadically so the situation is hard to track.

My question is:  Do I need to call [fHandle synchronizeFile]  to make sure the data goes to permanent storage?   Is there a chance that iOS will lose data from the file buffers before it is sent to permanent storage resulting in 0 size file when I reopen the app?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the NSFileHandle result when writing data, but I would suggest using NSData's `writeToFile:atomically:` method, as the "atomically" flag achieves just what you're asking about - it guarantees that either all data is written, or none is.

Comment: Great, but what if he needs a file handle to a TCP socket? then you are screwed with `writeToFile:`. I wouldn't really suggest using this if multiple data outputs is wanted.

Comment: Actually I need to write in a loop getting data from multiple places and writeToFile:atomically is not an option in this case.

Comment: Gotcha, then the file handle is necessary

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsfilehandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000304-DontLinkElementID_34), this is guaranteed:

```
synchronizeFile
Causes all in-memory data and attributes of the file represented 
by the receiver to be written to permanent storage.

- (void)synchronizeFile

Discussion
This method should be invoked by programs that require the 
file to always be in a known state. An invocation of this 
method does not return until memory is flushed.
```

So as long as you call `synchronizeFile`, you can be sure that all content you have written is flushed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it doesn't needed to be called (maybe unless you do some very tricky threading/GCD/whatever). For me, it's sufficient to simply call writeData: and closeFile.